# installing python libraries

Tags: python, package-management

Ok, so i've downloaded the following library:
http://www.lag.net/paramiko/

and i can't seem to figure out how to install on my local machine:
Mac OS X 10.4.11

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To use the package that you got from the web-site: "python setup.py install
"

My advice is to use easy_install instead of downloading packages straight from the project web-site.

To do this, you must first install [setuptools](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools).

Then just use the command "easy_install paramiko".

As you use lots of different packages, this ends up saving you lots of hassle.

Comment: Note that setuptools, though very commonly used, is non-standard. The standard is to use the package's `setup.py` directly.